# rm no longer asking for confirmation when deleting files?

Tags: linux, centos, bash, centos6, rm

On my CentOS 6.9 box I've just spotted that `rm myfile` no longer asks me if I really want to delete it, it just deletes it.

I've run `alias` and there's nothing to do with `rm` there.

What else could be making it act as if I'd supplied `-f` when I haven't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, `rm` does not ask for confirmation before deletion. To force it to ask for confirmation, you can use the `-i` switch or define an alias like:

```
alias rm='rm -i'
```

There are cases when it asks for confirmation without specifying any option like `-i` or `-f` such as when you are removing a read-only file (no write permission).

Comment: Ah that makes sense.  I managed to nuke my .bashrc file the other day so I must have previously had an alias set up in there that WAS enabling the confirmation, e.g. `alias rm="rm -i"`

Comment: BTW typically for root 3 aliases are set : `alias rm='rm -i'` , 
`alias cp='cp -i'` & 
`alias mv='mv -i'`

Comment: Thanks.  I look at a .bashrc from another box that I have and saw those too. Much appreciated to both of you!

Comment: Is there a way to get sudo to honor the alias?